# How do we handle questions, where there just isn't a final answer, only opinions?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385947/creating-a-contingency-table) question. I think that there is no final answer.

Since there are 2 votes for the question, it seems to be interesting. And since there are 4 formatting-suggestions, there seem to be different opinions.

Maybe other users want to provide their solution and maybe after a while the community will have voted up its most popular solutions and give other users a chance to decide on their own which they want to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are often multiple solutions to the same problem (one could call them opinions).  For such a case the model of Stackexchange was invented, where better solutions get more upvotes and the questioner decides which one fits best in his context by marking one as accepted answer.

On the other hand, if the question leaves too much space for opinion, e.g.

- ”What is the best way to do [...]?”
- ”Which [...] do you recommend?”

it should be closed as primarily opinion-based.  It's the last option in the close dialog.

[image]

Comment: So, opinion-based questions aren't wanted?

Comment: @Ben Broadly no: the StackOverflow model is that the questions have answers that can be judged reasonably objectively. 'Comparison' questions may be OK if they are objective: see for example the big list of IDEs one.

Comment: @JosephWright (at) Henri Menke I updated my question while it was on hold and actually expected it to be re-opened (like written in the Help Center). Now it's closed. Does it still not fit the rules? If so, why?

Comment: @Ben “How would you format a table like this?” is clearly opinion-based. Better ask things like “How do I get horizontal rules?” or “How to format this table with `booktabs`?” etc.

Comment: @HenriMenke sorry I missed the part under the code.

Comment: @Ben It's still a bit unclear to me, but it's much better than most other questions, so I voted to reopen.  Also you should accept one of the answers.